# Anybody know this font?

Tags: fonts, font-identification, font-recommendation

I've tried "what the font" and didn't get anything really close. It has kind of a permanent marker feel to it. Would appreciate if anyone knows this or a similar font.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I vote for [poetsenone](http://www.dafont.com/poetsen-one.font?text=0508%20DONT%20RISK%20IT) font, considering the image blur it looks very close to the sample:

[image]